# Buttons don't work after creating a Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm working on a project and I need to add a modal to it, before creating my modal, Buttons were working fine and functions were executing normaly, but after creating the modal, only the modal buttons are working, and the page buttons don't, I tried removing the html of the modal and they worked fine(that's how I understood that problem is with the modal), I also tried to remove the overlay but nothing changed .
I've just tried to remove the css of the modal and the overlay and It's working fine, so maybe there's a problem there ?

Here's the code of the modal:

```js
//modal part

const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const overlay = document.querySelector('#overlay');
const closeModalBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');

const backProjectBtn = document.querySelector('.join-btn');
const selectRewardBtn = document.querySelector('.select-reward-btn');

backProjectBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal)

function openModal(){
    modal.classList.add('active');
    overlay.classList.add('active'); 
}

closeModalBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

function closeModal(){
    
    modal.classList.remove('active');
    overlay.classList.remove('active');
}
```

```css
/* modal styling*/

.modal{
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
}
.modal.active{
    opacity: 1;
}
.modal-header{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
#overlay{
    background: hsla(0, 0%, 48%, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;

}
#overlay.active{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.close-btn{
    background: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pledging-block{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 90%;
    border: 0.5px solid hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
}

span{
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: hsl(176, 50%, 47%);
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.header-infos-mahogany{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.title{
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.money-block{
    border-top: 0.5px solid hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
}

.infos-mahogany-pladging, .black-pledging-radio{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}
.left{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.header-infos-bamboo, .header-infos-black, .header-infos-mahogany{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.enter-value{
    width: 25%;
    border: hsl(176, 50%, 47%) 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.radio-label{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid hsl(176, 50%, 47%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-label .checkmark{
    width: calc(100% - 5%);
    height:  calc(100% - 5%);
    background-color: hsl(176, 50%, 47%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: none;
}

.radio-label input{
    display: none;
}
.radio-label input:checked + .checkmark{
    display: inline-block;
}
.label-part{
    width: 10%;
}

.mahogany-pledging{
    opacity: 0.5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="interactive-div">
                    <button class="joinbtn">Backthisproject</button>
                    <button class="bookmark-btn"><img src="images/icon-bookmark.svg" class="bookmark-icon"><div class="text">Bookmark</div></button>
                </div>

<div class="modal" >
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Back this project </h1>
                <button class="close-btn">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <p>Want to support us in bringing Mastercraft Bamboo Monitor Riser out in the world?</p>
            
            <div class="no-reward-pledging pledging-block">
                <div class="label-part">
                    <label class="radio-label">
                        <input type="radio"  id="no-reward-pledging-radio" name="radio">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="infos-no-reward">
                    <div class="title">Plegde with no reward</div>
                    <p>Choose to support us without a reward if you simply believe in our project. As a backer, you will be signed up to receive product updates via email.</p>
                    <div class="money-block">
                        <p>Enter your plegde</p>
                        <div class="entering-money">
                            <input type="number" class="enter-value">
                            <button class="continue-btn">Continue</button>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>  
                
            </div>
            <div class="bamboo-pledging pledging-block">
                <div class="label-part">
                    <label class="radio-label">
                        <input type="radio"  id="no-reward-pledging-radio" name="radio">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="infos-bamboo-pladging">
                    <div class="header-infos-bamboo">
                        <div class="title">Bamboo Stand <span>   Pledge $25 or more</span></div>
                        <div class="left">
                            <div class="num-left">101</div>
                            <p class="left">left</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>You get an ergonomic stand made of natural bamboo. You've helped us launch our promotional campaign, and you’ll be added to a special Backer member list..</p>
                    <div class="money-block">
                    <p>Enter your plegde</p>
                    <div class="entering-money">
                        <input type="number" class="enter-value">
                        <button class="continue-btn">Continue</button>
                    </div>
                    
                        
                    </div>

                    
                </div>   
            </div>
            <!-- I removed some elements as they are almost identical -->
```

I removed some elements as they are almost identical

Comment: You are missing the HTML element with class `join-btn`, and because of that your code snippet won't work.

Comment: I would have to add all of my html for it, should I ?

Comment: Well if it's not extremely large, or something that you would not like other people to see, you should add it.

Comment: I've only added the div where there is the button, hope that's enough

Comment: is it the `selectRewardBtn` perhaps destroying the modal destroys its event handler.

Comment: I don't understand why would it ?

Comment: hard to tell without a working version demonstrating the bug.

Comment: I can send you the website that can maybe help

Comment: link to  jsfiddle.net if its large.

Comment: https://crowdfunding-landing-page.lyndabelfar1.repl.co/

Comment: the modal will appear by adding the active class to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the css of my modal

```
.modal{
background: white;
border: 1px solid white;
border-radius: 15px;
padding: 30px;
width: 60%;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
z-index: 10;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}

.modal.active{
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).